# How can I serialize multiple unrelated tables to get combined JSON output via django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am working on an order management. **Here's the scenario**: **User can create multiple types of orders and these order types are unrelated, but user can view all types of order**.
I have created an individual table for each of order type in `models.py`

```py
class OrderType1(models.Model):
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="create_time")
    ordertype1_info = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name="Exclusive info for OrderType1")

class OrderType2(models.Model):
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="create_time")
    ordertype2_info = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name="Exclusive info for OrderType2")

class OrderType3(models.Model):
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="create_time")
    ordertype3_info = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name="Exclusive info for OrderType3")
```

In `serializers.py`, I have created serializers accordingly

```py
class OrderType1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderType1
        fields="__all__"

class OrderType2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderType2
        fields="__all__"

class OrderType3Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderType3
        fields="__all__"
```

Then here's **the key problem**: I want to create a serializer of order to return all orders of mutilple types like

```py
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = [OrderType1, OrderType2, OrderType3]
        fields = "common info of all types of order"
```

If the serializer accepts GET request, I want to return **JSON output** like this:

```json
{
    "OrderType1":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "create_time": "2018-01-01 12:00:00",
            "ordertype1_info": "Exclusive info for OrderType1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "create_time": "2019-12-01 12:00:00",
            "ordertype1_info": "Exclusive info for OrderType1"
        }
    ],
    "OrderType2":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "create_time": "2020-01-01 12:00:00",
            "ordertype1_info": "Exclusive info for OrderType2"
        }
    ],
    "OrderType3":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "create_time": "2021-01-01 09:00:00",
            "ordertype1_info": "Exclusive info for OrderType3"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "create_time": "2022-12-01 10:00:00",
            "ordertype1_info": "Exclusive info for OrderType3"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "create_time": "2022-12-01 10:20:30",
            "ordertype1_info": "Exclusive info for OrderType3"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I design a serializer (or a viewset?) to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question immediatly, I was wondering, have you ever considered using a slightly more generic approach like this:

```
ORDER_TYPE_CHOICES = [
    ('type1', 'OrderType1'),
    ('type2', 'OrderType2'),
    ('type3', 'OrderType3'),
]

class Order(models.Model):
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="create_time")
    order_type = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=ORDER_TYPE_CHOICES)
    order_info = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name="Order Info")
```

This will make things easier when it comes down to serializing, deserializing, database queries, etc.

If this is absolutely not what you are looking for and doesn't help you, you can look at something like this:

```
class YourAPIView(APIView):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Fetch all orders for each type
    orders_type1 = OrderType1.objects.all()
    orders_type2 = OrderType2.objects.all()
    orders_type3 = OrderType3.objects.all()

    # Serialize the orders
    serialized_type1 = OrderType1Serializer(orders_type1, many=True).data
    serialized_type2 = OrderType2Serializer(orders_type2, many=True).data
    serialized_type3 = OrderType3Serializer(orders_type3, many=True).data

    # Create the response format
    response_data = {
        "OrderType1": serialized_type1,
        "OrderType2": serialized_type2,
        "OrderType3": serialized_type3
    }

    return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Joris' answer that combines the serializers in the written view class, you can also define a new unified serializer using `serializers.Serializer` for this combination as follows:

```py
# serializers.py

...

class UnifiedSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    order_type1 = OrderType1Serializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    order_type2 = OrderType2Serializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    order_type3 = OrderType3Serializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

Then you would need a view and the respective url for in order that:

```py
# views.py

class UnifiedView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        queryset1 = OrderType1.objects.all()
        queryset2 = OrderType2.objects.all()
        queryset3 = OrderType3.objects.all()

        serializer = UnifiedSerializer({
            'order_type1': OrderType1Serializer(queryset1, many=True).data,
            'order_type2': OrderType2Serializer(queryset2, many=True).data,
            'order_type3': OrderType3Serializer(queryset3, many=True).data,
        })

        return Response(serializer.data)
```